MapView In react native keeps coming up with a web bundling error?
new to all this but im having problems with using MapView in my react native app i keep getting a web bundling failed when i add the import map view, any help will be appreciated here is my code and the error output im getting, probably a simple fix.
import React from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

import { View, Text, StyleSheet  } from 'react-native';

export default function MapScreen() {
return (
\<View style={styles.container}\>

        <Text>The Map</Text>
      
       <MapView style={styles.map}></MapView>
      </View>
      
    );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
backgroundColor: 'plum',
},

map: {
width:'100%',
height: '100%',
}

});


Web Bundling failed 2082ms C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\React\LandmarkFinder3\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js (607 modules)
Unable to resolve "../Utilities/Platform" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactPrivate\ReactNativePrivateInterface.js"
